# Suppress auto-complete imports from certain folders in WebStorm

Tags: angular, webstorm

When importing annotations/decorators from Angular 2 in WebStorm (e.g. @Component, @Input, @Output, etc.) WebStorm auto-completes the import with the path:

```
`import {Component, Input, Output} from 'angular2/src/core/metadata';
```

instead of from `'angular2/core'`.

Is there a way to fix this behavior of where WebStorm is looking?

A hacky solution seems to find a way to tell WebStorm not to even look in the `'angular2/src'` directory, but I'm sure how to do that.

Is there a better solution out there?  I can fix them all manually but it's just a pain.

Comment: "angular2/core" is a deprecated version. WS correctly works for angular2 1.0 and higher (the import should be "@angular/core").

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to Angular and have been following a tutorial.  I hadn't realized the package name had changed.